# How to use order by clause in inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a large trouble with order by clause in my inner query.
I use this query to get paged results from database:

```
;WITH ItemsRank AS
(
select
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.CreatedOnDate) AS RowNum, 
t.ItemId
from Tickets t
where t.CompanyId = @CompanyId
group by t.ItemId ...

order by t.CreatedOnDate desc -- this makes me trouble

) ,x as (
select ItemsRank.*, 
c.CommentText ...

WHERE RowNum > @p_From
    AND RowNum <= @p_From + 50
)
select * from x where RowNumComment <= 4
```

*Because query is large I removed all selects, joing, groups etc.*

If I put order by at the end of query it works but not as expected.
Because first part of query should get top 50 results in descending order.

This is the error that I get:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified

What am I doing wrong? 
Is it possible to fix this query to get ordered items in first part of the query?

Comment: You should start putting the semicolon at the end of the statemet: http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/why-i-will-begin-using-semicolons-to-terminate-sql-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error indicates, you cannot use `ORDER BY` in CTEs.

That `ORDER BY` is not necessary. You specify the order in the `OVER` clause. You can `ORDER BY RowNum` in your final query.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see that I miss `desc` in `OVER` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Error itself gives you all the info about why it can't be used... :) As @flem said. try this and set as you desire the order.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.CreatedOnDate desc) AS RowNum,
```

Or else you could create the `CTE` without `order by` and then use a `select` with `order by`. 
Read more on [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/23/sql-server-order-by-does-not-work-limitation-of-the-views-part-1/).